# iOS line measurement on picture

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need some help to get started on drawing lines with circle at ends, and measure its length. I am able to draw the line but can't make it moving,having spent hours decided to post on SO.

So please see below image and guide me to get started. Any sample or tutorial using objective c will help.

[image]

Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This idea looked like fun to implement, so I started a new project in Xcode and created a proof-of-concept.

### LineView (UIView subclass)

This class is responsible for drawing two circles and a line connecting their centers.

```
class LineView: UIView {

    var startPoint: CGPoint?
    var endPoint: CGPoint?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.multipleTouchEnabled = true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.updatePointsWithTouches(touches)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.updatePointsWithTouches(touches)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.clearPoints()
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.clearPoints()
    }

    private func updatePointsWithTouches(touches: Set<UITouch>) {
        if touches.count >= 1 {
            self.startPoint = touches[advance(touches.startIndex, 0)].locationInView(self)
        }

        if touches.count >= 2 {
            self.endPoint = touches[advance(touches.startIndex, 1)].locationInView(self)
        }

        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    private func clearPoints() {
        self.startPoint = nil
        self.endPoint = nil
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }



    // MARK: - Drawing

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // draw circle at startPoint
        if let sp = self.startPoint {
            self.drawTouchCircleAtPoint(sp)
        }

        // draw circle at endPoint
        if let ep = self.endPoint {
            self.drawTouchCircleAtPoint(ep)
        }

        // draw line between points
        if let sp = self.startPoint, ep = self.endPoint {
            self.drawLineBetweenFirstPoint(sp, secondPoint: ep)
        }
    }

    private func drawTouchCircleAtPoint(p: CGPoint) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSaveGState(context)

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0)
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.6)

        CGContextAddArc(context, p.x, p.y, CGFloat(30.0), CGFloat(0.0), CGFloat(M_PI * 2), 1)
        CGContextFillPath(context)

        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    }

    private func drawLineBetweenFirstPoint(p1: CGPoint, secondPoint p2: CGPoint) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSaveGState(context)

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6).CGColor)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0)

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, p1.x, p1.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, p2.x, p2.y)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)

        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    }
}
```

This class introduces two private properties: `startPoint` and `endPoint`, which keep track of where the user's fingers are touching the view.

In this class you'll find a `setup()` function that is called from all the initializers. `self.multipleTouchEnabled = true` is crucial here so the view can detect multiple touches at the same time.

The `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended/Cancelled` functions call helper functions that extract the locations of the `UITouch` instances in the `touches` set.

Finally, the last three functions are responsible for drawing the circles and the connecting line.

### InteractiveImageView (UIImageView subclass)

```
class InteractiveImageView: UIImageView {

    private var lineView: LineView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.lineView = LineView(frame: self.bounds)
        self.addSubview(self.lineView)
    }

}
```

This `UIImageView` subclass has an embedded `LineView` to capture the multi-touch events.

---

You can use these classes with a Storyboard too! Just drag out a `UIImageView`, change it's class to `InteractiveImageView`, set the proper constraints, and run the app. I'll leave it up to you to draw the text on the axis between the center of the circles.

Here's a picture of my proof-of-concept.
[image]

---

For those looking for an Objective-C solution, please see below for the implementation files of `LineView` and `InteractiveImageView`.

### LineView (in Objective-C)

```
#import "LineView.h"

@interface LineView ()

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint startPoint;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint endPoint;

@end

@implementation LineView

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setup
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.multipleTouchEnabled = true;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self updatePointsWithTouches:touches];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self updatePointsWithTouches:touches];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self clearPoints];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self clearPoints];
}

- (void)clearPoints
{
    self.startPoint = CGPointZero;
    self.endPoint = CGPointZero;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)updatePointsWithTouches:(NSSet *)touches
{
    if (touches.count >= 1) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches allObjects][0];
        self.startPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    }

    if (touches.count >= 2) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches allObjects][1];
        self.endPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (self.startPoint.x != 0 && self.startPoint.y != 0) {
        [self drawTouchCircleAtPoint:self.startPoint];
    }

    if (self.endPoint.x != 0 && self.endPoint.y != 0) {
        [self drawTouchCircleAtPoint:self.endPoint];
    }

    if (self.endPoint.x != 0 && self.endPoint.y != 0 &&
        self.startPoint.x != 0 && self.startPoint.y != 0) {
        [self drawLineBetweenFirstPoint:self.startPoint end:self.endPoint];
    }
}

- (void)drawLineBetweenFirstPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint end:(CGPoint)endPoint
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

- (void)drawTouchCircleAtPoint:(CGPoint)CirclePoint
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.6);

    CGContextAddArc(context, CirclePoint.x, CirclePoint.y, 30.0, 30.0,  M_PI * 2, YES);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

@end
```

### InteractiveImageView (in Objective-C)

```
#import "InteractiveImageView.h"
#import "LineView.h"

@interface InteractiveImageView ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) LineView *lineView;

@end

@implementation InteractiveImageView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setup
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.lineView = [[LineView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [self addSubview:self.lineView];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you so much ,, your logic is very helpful.. My bad I forgot to add objective-c in question.. But I am learning from ur code and trying to accomplish it in obj c,.... Great work

Comment: I am always getting touches count = 1 in the function   updatePointsWithTouches(touches: Set<UITouch>) ... not sure why this is happening.... Any idea's?

Comment: Try adding `self.multipleTouchEnabled = true` to the `setup()` function in the image view subclass.

Comment: no luck.. Here is the gist https://gist.github.com/akhildave/0381f3aed55abbc9e730   Thanks

Comment: Oh my suggestion was in Swift. In Objective-C you would add `self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES` to the `setup()` function in the image view subclass. Does that work?

Comment: Multi touch is enabled on Image view also.. I checked with boolean flag  if(self.self.multipleTouchEnabled)  and it returns true... For some reason it doesn't work .. no luck yet.. am trying to solve it..

Comment: @Dave Okay, I'm also trying to translate my code to Objective-C right now. Let me know if you figure it out.

Comment: @Dave Hmm, everything is working as expected for me. I translated it to Objective-C.

Comment: InteractiveImageView is subclass of UiImageView and LineView is sub class of UiView right ? How have u inked it in above code. Please let me know.

Comment: Are you testing on a device or the simulator?

Comment: I get an error "Cannot find Interface declaration for LineView".. I use XCODE 6 and testing on simulator. Please update me

Comment: @Dave Did you declare `LineView` in `LineView.h`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81669/discussion-between-dave-and-ndmeiri).

Comment: For others, the problem turned out to be that the OP wasn't testing the code with two fingers on the screen at once. So the behavior he observed was actually expected.

Comment: Yes. I had to use OPTION key on my keyboard with touch. Because i was testing on simulator..Thanks