# iOS resize or re-position line on dragging end points

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to resize the line, by touching the red circle points. Let's say, I want to move this line above lips in the image below, How can i achieve this. The line is not moving from the position. I have just started up with this thing and can't find much relevant resources to accomplish this. Trying the best...Please guide me in the right direction. Below is my code and reference image.

Objective c code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(100, 100) radius:10 startAngle:0 endAngle:6.2831853 clockwise:TRUE];
    
    //Add second circle
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
    
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(200, 200) radius:10 startAngle:0 endAngle:6.2831853 clockwise:TRUE];

    
    [path closePath];
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    [path stroke];
    [path fill];
    
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    
}
```

[image]

I will add multiple lines like this and my ultimate aim is to move individual line at any position in the image and get measurement of that area using line size.

**EDIT:**
The scenario is, at any given time there will be some flexible lines available on the screen. Lets's say by clicking button, one more new line will be added to screen. The user can just drag any end point to resize the line in any direction. I can't get this thing working correctly.. no luck.

Here is my gist file link,
https://gist.github.com/akhildave/3a8bec5b4df95cc06822
It basically adds a UIView to create a line on image. The code in gist allows me to resize the line height by moving touch points up and down but doesn't allow me to rotate the angle of line and adding text in the centre.
THANKS

Thanks!

Comment: Would you like each endpoint to be moved one at a time? Or both at the same time?

Comment: unfortunately,, it has to move one at a time by touching on line any end point... this post was old and unanswered too .. still stuck with this feature.. it should not use multi touch,, because of requirement :)

Comment: Alright sounds good. I'll see what I can whip up tomorrow. And you're looking for a way to have multiple lines per image, right?

Comment: yes, multiple lines on image.. Each line will have only two points.  Thnx.. I am working towards it,, If I succeed i will also post the answer here too  :)

Comment: Will the lines ever need to be curved?

Comment: I suggest you look at https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot. Add a transparent `CPTXYGraph` above your image and you can now draw line, add text annotation ....

Comment: @ndmeri no... lInes will be straight

Comment: @ndmeiri solved it by adding image views for draggable points and drawing lines between them.. not sure if it is correct way .. but works great

Comment: In my opinion that is not the correct way because it introduces twice the computational overhead for each new line you add, which is unnecessary. Take a look at my solution below which uses `drawRect:` to create the lines, which is much more efficient even with many lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time,, This was my first approach towards core graphics...I see you have done something great.. I appreciate your approach towards the problem.

Comment: @ndmeiri I like your approach and started a bounty, I definitely want to award it to you for your interest and introducing me to advance level by  making use of sub classes in IOS.. Thanks

Comment: @ndmeiri i will be able to award the bounty point only after 24 hrs of starting it .. I think with time,, this answer will earn lot more points than you have thought.. > 1000  :D

Comment: Thanks @Dave, I appreciate that :) Feel free to unaccept my answer to see if that attracts other to try to earn the bounty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[One of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31068243/5007059) can be extended to include the features you're trying to implement. You need to implement two classes: `LineView` and `LineImageView`.

Before we start, take a look at this animated gif of the finished demo.

[image]

Note that the "Add Line" button was added in a storyboard and is not a subview of the image view. Create your button, style it, and then hook it up to an `IBAction` that calls `[self.lineImageView addLineView]`.

### UIViewController Subclass Implementation

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "LineImageView.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet LineImageView *lineImageView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)addLineTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.lineImageView addLineView];
}

@end
```

### LineView Interface

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LineView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint startPoint;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint endPoint;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat circleRadius; // defaults to 30.0

@end
```

### LineView Implementation

```
#import "LineView.h"

@interface LineView ()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL startPointTracking;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL endPointTracking;

@end

@implementation LineView

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
        self.startPoint = [self randomPointInBounds];
        self.endPoint = [self randomPointInBounds];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setup
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.multipleTouchEnabled = false; // multi-touch is not allowed
    self.circleRadius = 30.0;
}

#pragma mark - Touch handling

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];

    if ([self pointIsOnStartCircle:location]) {
        self.startPointTracking = YES;
        self.endPointTracking = NO;
    } else if ([self pointIsOnEndCircle:location]) {
        self.startPointTracking = NO;
        self.endPointTracking = YES;
    }

    [self updatePointsWithTouches:touches];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self updatePointsWithTouches:touches];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.startPointTracking = NO;
    self.endPointTracking = NO;
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.startPointTracking = NO;
    self.endPointTracking = NO;
}

- (void)updatePointsWithTouches:(NSSet *)touches
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if (self.startPointTracking) {
        self.startPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];

    } else if (self.endPointTracking) {
        self.endPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event
{
    return [self pointIsOnStartCircle:point] || [self pointIsOnEndCircle:point];
}

#pragma mark - Drawing

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if ([self isHidden]) { return; }

    [self drawTouchCircleAtPoint:self.startPoint];
    [self drawTouchCircleAtPoint:self.endPoint];
    [self drawLineBetweenFirstPoint:self.startPoint end:self.endPoint];
    [self drawDistanceText];
}

- (void)drawLineBetweenFirstPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint end:(CGPoint)endPoint
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

- (void)drawTouchCircleAtPoint:(CGPoint)CirclePoint
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.6);

    CGContextAddArc(context, CirclePoint.x, CirclePoint.y, self.circleRadius, 30.0,  M_PI * 2, YES);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

- (void)drawDistanceText
{
    CGPoint midpoint = [self midpointBetweenFirstPoint:self.startPoint secondPoint:self.endPoint];

    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
    UIColor *textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textColor};
    NSString *distanceString = [self formattedDistanceString];

    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:distanceString attributes:attributes];

    [attributedString drawAtPoint:midpoint];
}

#pragma mark - Helper methods

- (CGPoint)randomPointInBounds
{
    int x = arc4random() % (int)CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds);
    int y = arc4random() % (int)CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds);
    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}

- (CGFloat)distanceFromPoint:(CGPoint)p1 toPoint:(CGPoint)p2
{
    CGFloat xDist = p2.x - p1.x;
    CGFloat yDist = p2.y - p1.y;
    return sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
}

- (CGPoint)midpointBetweenFirstPoint:(CGPoint)p1 secondPoint:(CGPoint)p2
{
    CGFloat x = (p1.x + p2.x) / 2.0;
    CGFloat y = (p1.y + p2.y) / 2.0;
    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}

- (BOOL)pointIsOnStartCircle:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGFloat distance = [self distanceFromPoint:point toPoint:self.startPoint];
    return distance <= self.circleRadius;
}

- (BOOL)pointIsOnEndCircle:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGFloat distance = [self distanceFromPoint:point toPoint:self.endPoint];
    return distance <= self.circleRadius;
}

- (NSString *)formattedDistanceString
{
    CGFloat distance = [self distanceFromPoint:self.startPoint toPoint:self.endPoint];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[self class] sharedFormatter];
    return [formatter stringFromNumber:@(distance)];
}

+ (NSNumberFormatter *)sharedFormatter
{
    static NSNumberFormatter *sharedFormatter = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedFormatter;
}
```

### LineImageView Interface

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LineImageView : UIImageView

- (void)addLineView;

@end
```

### LineImageView Implementation

```
#import "LineImageView.h"
#import "LineView.h"

@interface LineImageView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *lineViews; // of LineView

@end

@implementation LineImageView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setup
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

- (void)addLineView
{
    LineView *lineView = [[LineView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [self addSubview:lineView];
    [self.lineViews addObject:lineView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two buttons to your imageView

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTouch:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Set action as

```
    - (IBAction) imageMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
    {
        CGPoint point = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
        UIControl *control = sender;
        control.center = point;
        // redraw line on movement
        [self drawLine];
    }
```

Draw line between this two buttons. That's way can easily help you to calculate touch points and length of your line

```
- (void)drawLine
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, button1.frame.origin.x, button1.frame.origin.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, button2.frame.origin.x, button2.frame.origin.y);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
}
```